# PPT and PDF to XPS or PNG with C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I cannot convert PPT to XPS or PNG to PDF file.

Two ways for this problem is:

First Way: Using COM Component Microsoft. For Example

> :Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint,Microsoft.Office.Core , ... .

My Code :

```
private static void PPT2XPS()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application powerpoint;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations presentations;
    powerpoint = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    presentations = powerpoint.Presentations;
    presentation = presentations.Open(@"d:\test.ppt", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides = presentation.Slides;
    for (int i = 1; i <= slides.Count; i++)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide = slides[i];
        String slideName = slide.Name;
        releaseCOM(slide);
        slide.Export(@"d:\test\" + i.ToString() + ".xps", "");
    }
}

private static void releaseCOM(object o)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o);
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        o = null;
    }
}
```

Second Way: Sending file to

> "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" printer With Process.

My Code :

```
 Process P = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    psInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
    string option = @"/t";
    string xps = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";
    string targetFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) +  @".xps";

    string Myargs = String.Format("{0} \"{1}\" \"{2}\" {0} \"{3}\"", option, filename, xps, targetFile);
    psInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psInfo.Arguments = Myargs;
    psInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    psInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

    P.StartInfo = psInfo;
    P.Start();
    P.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Third Way: Using API Windows And Sending Binary File . 
This is sample for this way :

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

**My Problem :**

First Way: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used

Second Way: Cannot Hidden Window and Close Window

Third Way: Cannot Create XPS File . di.OutPutFile Create ill [bad?] file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Owner this Answer : [Emmanuel N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972124/emmanuel-n)**

You can do it like this or this for pdf/word. You can also use [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2008/09/24/convert-office-documents-docx-pptx-pub-into-pdf-programmatically.aspx), like this

Answer (score 1):

Your first direction seems to be the right one, but I don't understand some of your code.

1) Why are you calling releaseCOM? Of course yo'll get the COM exception you're describing, since you're releasing the COM object in one line, and then trying to access its methods. Drop the releaseCOM call inside your loop.

2) You're calling `slide.Export` with two parameters, the file name and an empty string. The second parameter should be the name of the graphic filter, not an empty string. Try passing ".xps" as the second parameter.

3) If you don't need each slide in its own separate file you can call `presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat("filename", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType.ppFixedFormatTypeXPS)`